# How do you log into Debian for the first time?

Tags: debian, login

I know the password that I set, but I don't know how to get past where it first says to log in!

Answer (score 1):

The `login` prompt is asking you for a [username](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_(computing)). What you probably want to do is enter `root` (for the [superuser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) account) and then enter the password you set (most likely, during installation).